# GPO without target pc

Tags: gpo

Is it possible to set up a GPO by using active directory groups but without specifying pc's?

I have 3 Active directory groups which I want to have MSMQ enabled for on the pc's they log on to. Can that be done? How?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should able to do this in the GPMC with the following,
Select your policy, then in the Scope tab (right hand pane) in the Security Filtering area select the Authenticated Users group and click Remove. Then click Add and search for the group names that you do want the policy applied to and add them in that Security Filtering pane. Then verify on the Delegation tab that those groups are listed and have Read access under Allowed Permissions, if necessary click Advanced and set that as necessary for each group.